# Can a class extends an ArrayList in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex

It is possible for a class to extend an arrayList of objects in Flex?

```
package classes
{
    import mx.collections.ArrayList;

    public class MenuItemList extends ArrayList<Object>
    {
        public function MenuItemList()
        {
            super();
        }
    }
}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is possible for a class to extend an arrayList of objects in Flex?

Any class not marked final can be extended, so yes a class can extend an ArrayList.

The syntax you are specifying `ArrayList<Object>` is used for [Vectors](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html) and I do not believe is valid with your current code.

Were you having some problem beyond that?

Comment: Thanks for the response. what if I want the menuitemList class to extend an arrayList of a class menuItem object. Something like this:    package classes
{
    import mx.collections.ArrayList;

    public class MenuItemList extends ArrayList<Object>
    {
        public function MenuItemList()
        {
            super();
        }
    }
}

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand.  A class can only extend a single class.  It sounds like you may be talking about multiple inheritance.  IF so, you should research interfaces.  If you wan to control the type of object added to your class, you'll have to extend that to throw erros when incorrect object types are added.